# Extrair dataframes de listas com dataframes sob determinado criterio no R

Tags: r

Eu organizei minha lista de dataframes assim:

```
df.1<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10),10,80))
df.1.in.list<-split.default(df.1, gl(10, 8))
```

Na lista `df.1.in.list` eu gostaria de manter apaenas os dataframes onde o primeiro elemento da coluna 8 seja 2 ou -2. Mantendo o carater de lista para `df.1.in.list`

Ou seja, retirar os dataframes que não se enquadram nesse critério.

Bem provavel que não haja casos desse tipo nesse exemplo q eu gerei. Mas meu dataframe original possui casos assim. Eu gostaria mesmo da ideia para ta promovendo essa seleção.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `keep` do `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

df.1.in.list %>%
  keep(~.x[1,8] %in% c(-2, 2))
```